# How to get a network path using net use, without having to map the path to a drive

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, path

So for example I have a network path `\\MY-PC\Folder`. I want a random PC in the network to just boot up and directly type `net use` to find the network path `\\MY-PC\Folder` without having to first map it to a drive and then type `net use` to get the path.

It would be a hassle to map a specific path for every computer if there are a lot of computers connected to the same network.

For some reason it once worked but then stopped working, with the `Local` being empty.

```
Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK                     \\KAZEM-PC\Shared         Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.
```

Comment: Using 'net use' specifically before actually mapping it?? I'm not certain `net use` is designed for that so consider using another method to get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I solved it by just typing `net view` which doesn't actually show you the full path, but at least shows you the main server path as in `\\SERVER-PC` which is still very helpful.